# How to do recurring code review efficiently in Bitbucket.org?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

In our company, we are using Bitbucket cloud edition. I'm wondering, do you guys have some ways of making recurring code review (I once did code review, author fixed comments, and then I come back to review again) more pleasant and easy?

Right now, after I'm going back to code review I have several problems:

- Old comments are accessible only through button "Outdated comments" - I'd prefer have every comment in respective place, when I'm reviewing but it can be marked that it is outdated
- Comments on removed files are very hard to review, because they are only accessible through Activity tab on the right - someone forgot doing `git mv`
- I miss button "Needs more work" which indicated that I already reviewed this code review and author didn't do any new commits
- Last but not least - why bitbucket is soooo slow???

If you guys have some ideas how to make reviewing code in Bitbucket cloud better, I'd appreciate hearing your tips.

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

I'm using for bitbucket cloud a chrome extension (also firefox) called Refined BitBucket
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/refined-bitbucket-/

This however does not answer your request features, but does a lot more:

#### Core features

- Syntax highlighting
- Custom Default Reviewers (upcoming)

  - made a standalone extension (https://github.com/jwallet/custom-default-reviewers)

#### BitBucket Improvements

- Show/hide comments and description
- Load all failed diffs
- Load all PR as ignore white space
- Collapse diff files, ignore files, auto-collapse files
- ...and more

Being able to load a PR and have the files already collapsed or some ignored make bitbucket load it a way faster.

This is the github page if you want to request a new feature, like add outdated comments to diff file instead of previous comment section : https://github.com/refined-bitbucket/refined-bitbucket/issues

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend BitBucket addon https://marketplace.atlassian.com/1221505
It provides separate board to maintain pull requests. You can easy drag PR in proper status (in preparation, ready for review, in review) so other developers/reviewers know exact status of PR 
This addon also provides other useful feature, f.e. show build status, tests availability etc